# Can you stop a nested child node from executing its constructor until a parent node has constructed?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Imagine a scenario where I have the following DOM tree

```
<body>
  <parent-component>
    <div>
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  </parent-component>
</body>
```

The child component has a `seekParent` function that fires off a `CustomEvent` that should be caught by the `<parent-component>`, which then uses a callback to tell the child this is the parent component node.

Consider when the child component is is defined via `customElements.define()` first. The child's constructor fires off the `CustomEvent` as soon as `<child-component>` is defined, since parent nodes do not need to be valid and at this stage be `HTMLUnknownElement`.

The event bubbles through the `<parent-component>` without being caught because that component has not yet called its constructor, to attach an event listener.

Is it at all possible to not parse child nodes within a DOM tree until a parent becomes defined / valid Element? Otherwise, is there any way around this issue besides using a `setTimeout()`?

Thanks

Comment: So you have a classroom where the teacher hasn't arrived yet. Then the children must respond on the teachers arrival. So reverse your Events, children listen for an event from the parent/teacher. Can also be done with a MutationObserver (created by the children)

Comment: There is also ``whenDefined``  (a Promise) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined What you use all depends on how tight you want the coupling between components to be.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I would like for child to listen to an event from parent, but as far as I know events only bubble up? I have also tried `whenDefined` but seems like that promise is fulfilled before the component constructor is executed.

Comment: Let children listen at ``document`` level (or any DOM element **_above_** parent) for a ``CustomEvent`` from a parent. Or attach a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), you don't need an Event then.

Comment: Right, but then you'd also be listening to components that are parents to other child elements, and even in the same node tree, not sure if it's the immediate parent. Could add additional logic to check though I guess

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make a component that delays the rendering until it's mounted:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      mounted: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({mounted: true});
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.mounted) return null;

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the child elements are JS managed and does not come from the HTML document. It would work, but I'm currently restricted to the case where these DOM nodes already exist in the document.